# where to keep secret key in flutter project?

Tags: flutter, secret-key

I have an app that uses a secret key for processing payments, and I've heard I need to keep it stored safely outside of the code that my app runs on (Flutter). Where should I store this key? How can I access the key without it being "hardcoded" on my app?

Answer (score 0):

I think one very viable option would be to use the Secret Manager provided by Google.

Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager

An alternative, although perhaps not as secure, could be storing some semi-secret information as (runtime) environment variables in Cloud Functions. Perhaps not good for payment keys, but could be ok for other API related configurations.

Depending on your application you could also consider using this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Answer (score 0):

Please use flutter secure storage: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

This package is used to store the user credentials or some useful
keys out of our flutter code.

This plugin internally stores the valueas at different location as per platfoem

On Android it is stored on Android keystore
On iOS it is stored in Apple keychain

Answer (score 0):

Secret key has to be exactly that, a secret.
You can not have it as part of your app in a plain form.
Moreover, even if you encrypt it and store the encrypted version that just means you now have a "new" secret that you have keep secret.
This is why we have authentication.

Make sure you're not confusing a secret key with a public key. A public key can safely be stored in your code.